# Class variable or object?

Tags: java, oop, object, syntax

If a program includes two classes named `Terrain` and `Simulation` and inside the `Terrain` class is the line:

```
private static Simulation sim;
```

Is that similar to creating a new object of the simulation class which can be achieved with the following syntax:

```
Simulation sim = new Simulation();
```

Or does it mean that `sim` is a variable of class type `Simulation`?

```
public class terrain {
    private static Simulation sim;

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}

public class Simulation {}
```

Comment: Best to read the introductory tutorials to see exactly what a variable is and what an object is. These are key concepts that you will want to understand cold.

Comment: The [Intro to Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) has plenty on static variables, and many examples of declarations of this type.

Comment: But it's the same -- you're declaring a static variable in both cases, in one a primitive and in another a reference variable. The only difference will be in the initial values which for an uninitialized reference variable will always be `null`

Comment: You can think of an object like some memory space that you can reserve to accomodate its attributes. In this case, Simulation is a variable (because you can assign values to it) AND it's an object (because it can be instantiated and be assigned with values to its attributes). I hope this can help to clarify :-)

Comment: @Leo: No, sorry for being a stickler but we can't give misinformation to newbies, and understanding of these concepts is critical. `Simulation` is **not** a variable. It's a type that's also a class. Only `sim` is the variable of Simulation type. `sim` can be assigned a `Simulation` object or an object of any type that is a child of `Simulation`.

Comment: ok, when I say "Simulation is a variable" I mean "sim is a variable of type Simulation". Is that better?

Comment: @Leo: yes much better thanks. Again the question is about key Java concepts, and we have to be precise and strict; lord knows the Java compiler sure is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Simulation sim;
```

That's a declaration of `static` (class) variable of `Simulation` type inside your `terrain` class.

> Does it mean that `sim` is a variable of class type `Simulation`?

Yes, indeed.

> Is that similar to creating a new object of the simulation class...?

No, you simply declared it, didn't initialize. I initialized it directly after the declaration:

```
private static Simulation sim = new Simulation();
```

Answer (score 0):

***Is that similar to creating a new object of the simulation class which can be achieved with the following syntax:***

no, with this `private static Simulation sim;` you are declaring an object of the class Simulation, this object below to the class `terrain` and not to the object that you instantiate of that class.

Answer (score 0):

`private static Simulation sim;` only declares a static, uninitialized variable.

You're still required to assign it to an instance, for example:

`private static Simulation sim = new Simulation();`